# React Native Android change scene navigator

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I'm trying to build a tabview and I can't find out how to change and render scenes. My main view is this one (App.js) :

```
<View style={{flex: 1}}>
  <TabView 
    ref="tabs"
    onTab={(tab) => {
      this.setState({tab});
    }}
    tabs={[
      {
        component: List,
        name: 'Découvrir',
        icon: require('../assets/img/tabs/icons/home.png')
      },
      {
        component: Friends,
        name: 'Amis',
        icon: require('../assets/img/tabs/icons/friend.png'),
        pastille: this.state.friendsPastille < 10 ? this.state.friendsPastille : '9+'
      },
      {
        component: RecoStep1,
        icon: require('../assets/img/tabs/icons/add.png'),
        hasShared: MeStore.getState().me.HAS_SHARED
      },
      {
        component: Notifs,
        name: 'Notifs',
        icon: require('../assets/img/tabs/icons/notif.png'),
        pastille: this.state.notifsPastille < 10 ? this.state.notifsPastille : '9+'
      },
      {
        component: Profil,
        name: 'Profil',
        icon: require('../assets/img/tabs/icons/account.png')
      }
    ]}
    initialSkipCache={!!this.notifLaunchTab}
    initialSelected={this.notifLaunchTab || 0}
    tabsBlocked={false} />
</View>
```

The TabView component is this one and it works fine. Only the navigator renders a blank screen only...

```
renderTab(index, name, icon, pastille, hasShared) {
  var opacityStyle = {opacity: index === this.state.selected ? 1 : 0.3};
  return (
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback key={index} style={styles.tabbarTab} onPress={() => {
      if (this.props.tabsBlocked) {
        return;
      }
      this.resetToTab(index);
    }}>
      <View style={styles.tabbarTab}>
        <Image source={icon} style={opacityStyle} />

        {name ?
          <Text style={[styles.tabbarTabText, opacityStyle]}>{name}</Text>
        : null}
      </View>
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
  );
}

resetToTab(index, opts) {
  this.setState({selected: index});
}

renderScene = (route, navigator) => {
  var temp = navigator.getCurrentRoutes();
  return temp[this.state.selected].component;
}

render() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.tabbarContainer}>
      <Navigator
        style={{backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF', paddingTop: 20}}
        initialRouteStack={this.props.tabs}
        initialRoute={this.props.tabs[this.props.initialSelected || 0]}
        ref="tabs"
        key="navigator"
        renderScene={this.renderScene}
        configureScene={() => {
          return {
            ...Navigator.SceneConfigs.FadeAndroid,
            defaultTransitionVelocity: 10000,
            gestures: {}
          };
        }} />

      {this.state.showTabBar ? [
         <View key="tabBar" style={styles.tabbarTabs}>
            {_.map(this.props.tabs, (tab, index) => {
            return this.renderTab(index, tab.name, tab.icon, tab.pastille, tab.hasShared);
            })}
        </View>
      ] : []}
    </View>
  );
}
```

I know I'm doing something wrong, but I can't figure out what ... Changing tabs doesn't display anything as shown below..
I used NavigatorIOS for ans iOS version that worked fine with the following navigator in the render method in TabView (I don't know how to go from the NavigatorIOS to Navigator) :

```
<Navigator
  style={{backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF', paddingTop: 20}}
  initialRouteStack={this.props.tabs}
  initialRoute={this.props.tabs[this.props.initialSelected || 0]}
  ref="tabs"
  key="navigator"
  renderScene={(tab, navigator) => {
    var index = navigator.getCurrentRoutes().indexOf(tab);
    return (
      <NavigatorIOS
        style={styles.tabbarContent}
        key={index}
        itemWrapperStyle={styles.tabbarContentWrapper}
        initialRoute={tab.component.route()}
        initialSkipCache={this.props.initialSkipCache} />
      );
  }}
  configureScene={() => {
    return {
      ...Navigator.SceneConfigs.FadeAndroid,
      defaultTransitionVelocity: 10000,
      gestures: {}
    };
  }} />
```

[image: The tabbar is here but the screen is white...]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found the answer : I changed my `renderScene` method to the following :

```
renderScene = (route, navigator) => {
  var temp = navigator.getCurrentRoutes();
  return React.createElement(temp[this.state.selected].component, _.extend({navigator: navigator}, route.passProps));
}
```

Works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a

```
flex:1
```

property to the navigator. If that doesn't work, check to see that the tabbarContainer also has a

```
flex:1
```

property.

Comment: TabBarContainer has `flex: 1`
Adding `flex: 1`to the navigator doesn't change anything. I think the problem comes from rendering the scenes. When I put : `renderScene = (route, navigator) => {return <Text>Hello World !</Text>}`
 Hello World is shown

Comment: Have you tried hard coding a route in there, just to see if that possibly works?

Comment: Yes, it works fine with hard coding a component.
`renderScene = (route, navigator) => {return <EditMe />;}` returns the component above the TabBar as expected...